# Prove the sequence $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {\sin(k)}{k^2}$ converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I'm stuck at this question.

I tried proving that the sequence converges through proving the sequence is Cauchy but I'm stuck there too.

My try : Let $\epsilon>0$ and $n\ge m$.

$$|a_n-a_m|=\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin(k)}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^m\frac{\sin(k)}{k^2}\right|\\
=\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{\sin(k)}{k^2}\right|$$

And exactly there I'm stuck.

How to prove it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Hint: You can show that the sum is convergent by recalling that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Comment: This is equivalent to the convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n^2}$.

Comment: Did you know you can enclose all the math at once in a single pair of (double) dollar signs?

Comment: If you want to use your method, note that $\left| \sum_{k = m+1}^n \frac{\sin(k)}{k^2} \right| \leq \sum_{k = m+1}^n \left| \frac{\sin(k)}{k^2} \right| \leq \sum_{k = m+1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \sum_{k = m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}  \leq \frac{1}{m}$. Choose $m = \epsilon^{-1}$ to complete your proof.

Comment: Yes @Randall , this is exactly what I was looking for (I saw that it can be also proved with the squeeze but I'm looking for the Cauchy proof). Thank you.

Comment: @Arthur Yes I know, It just caused me problems with double dollar signs in the Title so I copied it into the main form and kept with 1 dollar sign.

Comment: @Roach87 Yes, double dollars in titles are considered bad (I didn't know there were technical issues, but it makes the title take up more space than it should on the front page).

Answer (score 0):

Note that$$\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac{\sin(k)}{k^2}\right|\leqslant\sum_{k=m+1}^n\frac1{k^2}$$and that the sequence $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}$ converges.

Comment: One can even conclude the given series converges absolutely.